# Name the plant please

Tags: identification, orchids

Name the plant, please. It may be an orchid.

[image]

Comment: Where in the world, is this growing wild? And it looks to be some sort of Orchid.

Comment: orchids are one of the most diverse groups of plants in the world... if it is common in your area then it probably has a name, and you can probably find someone locally that knows what it is... if it isn't wild, then it is almost certainly some sort of hybrid...

Comment: Just counting known naturally-occurring species, there are over 21,000 orchid species. They are native to virtually everywhere that isn't under a glacier. Just to start with I think we need to know where you found this, both in terms of geography and in terms of local habitat. And a picture of the rest of the plant wouldn't hurt.